# execute shell script as root in java code

Tags: java, shell

How to run .sh file as a root in this code?
in the main section i run my .sh file from desire directory. But i got permission denied when i run. I simple want my .sh code run as root. Is there any way?

```html
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
    import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
    import org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException;

    public class TestScript {
        int iExitValue;
        String sCommandString;

        public void runScript(String command){
            sCommandString = command;
            CommandLine oCmdLine = CommandLine.parse(sCommandString);
            DefaultExecutor oDefaultExecutor = new DefaultExecutor();
            oDefaultExecutor.setExitValue(0);
            try {
                iExitValue = oDefaultExecutor.execute(oCmdLine);
            } catch (ExecuteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.err.println("Execution failed.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.err.println("permission denied.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String args[]){
            TestScript testScript = new TestScript();
            testScript.runScript("sh /home/deepak/Desktop/ftpusers.sh");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either run your Java application as a root, or execute the `ftpusers.sh` using some king of [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) command. I can see two possible options here:

1. If your application is started with an X Server, you can call the `ftpusers.sh` using `gksudo`, `kdesudo`or similar - it will prompt user if he is ok to run the application as root and probably ask for the password.
2. If your application is a console one, you will have to use the `sudo` command and manually redirect the IO from this command to the IO of your application

Please note that this approach won't work on all environments (sudo might be unavailable for example), so I would just change the `"permission denied."` message to something like `"Application foor must be started as root"` and ask user to run the Java application with proper permissions

Comment: I'm using netbeans.. How to implement now? Please help

Comment: @DeepakKr.Karn try something like: _testScript.runScript("gksudo sh /home/deepak/Desktop/ftpusers.sh");_

Comment: one more help sir..
How can i pass username and password in shell script using java?

Comment: @DeepakKr.Karn if you are using an UI tool for prompting the password (like _gksudo_) it will be too tricky. If you use the console version (_sudo_) you need to get the _InputStream_ of this process and wirte the password there

Comment: i'm using console sir. now please elaborate how to pass username and password to the script using java and then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Either run your java program as root, or run a [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) script to elevate your permissions. If the latter, ensure that no unauthorized users have access to the script.

Comment: I'm using netbeans to run above code. And i did not get what you said..Please explain..